# Android-Views in Relativelayout visible even after replacing it with another fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-relativelayout

The Relativelayout(R.id.relativeLayout1) in activity_main.xml is replaced with the fragment layout hotel_search.But after replacing the relativelayout with fragment the original views of the relativelayout are still visible.
Screenshot included.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context="com.example.jobinsabu.georgetravels.MainActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/homeflight"
                android:background="@drawable/homeflightcircle"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            </Button>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="flights"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_below="@+id/homeflight"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/homeflight"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/homeflight"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/homehotelcircle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/homeflight"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/homehotel" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hotels"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/homeholidaycircle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/homehotel"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/viewpager"
                android:id="@+id/button" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="holidays"
                android:id="@+id/holidaytext"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />
 </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

hotel_search.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="#60212121">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autohotellocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locationtext"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Hotel Name/City/Code"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/autohotellocation"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:background="#00838F"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"></View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="CheckIn"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/locationtext"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/locationtext"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkindate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="18"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="23sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkindate"
                android:text="Jun 2015"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:background="#00838F"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"></View>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view2">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/roomlayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/rooms"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/adults"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/rooms"

                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
                        android:text="Adults"
                        android:textColor="#BDBDBD" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/adults"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rooms"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rooms"
                        android:background="#90006064"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="22sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/adults"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/adults"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"

                        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
                        android:background="#90006064"
                        android:text="+"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/children"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
                        android:text="Children"
                        android:textColor="#BDBDBD" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"

                        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                        android:background="#90006064"
                        android:text="+"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:background="#90006064"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
            android:text="CheckOut"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkout"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkout"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkoutdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="18"

                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="23sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkoutdate"
                android:text="Jun 2015"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.jobinsabu.georgetravels;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.homehotel);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                HotelSearch hotelSearch=new HotelSearch();
                FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayout1,hotelSearch);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HotelSearch.java:

```
package com.example.jobinsabu.georgetravels;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Jobin Sabu on 4/5/2016.
 */
public class HotelSearch extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.hotel_search,null,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Give background color white to the fragment layout.

Comment: This is due to the transparency. Add different background color to fragments and see the changes

Answer (score 1):

Fragment doesn't work that way. `FragmentTransaction.replace` will remove an attached **fragment** and add the new one to the layout.

But those ViewPager and Button are not inside a Fragment but it's hardcoded to be laid in Activity's layout so FragmentTransaction cannot remove those views out.

What to do?

Leave that relativeLayout1 empty and group those child views inside as a Fragment. And then you will be able to remove them as you want.

Comment: I have made the relativelayout empty and grouped all the views in another  layout and I have done added the fragment to the relativelayout.It works fine till now.But now when I click the button in the fragment layout an other layout called hotel_search must replace the relativelayout,but I get an IllegalArgumentException( java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0051 (com.example.jobinsabu.georgetravels:id/relativeLayout1) for fragment HotelSearch{9a3d93 #0 id=0x7f0c0051})

Answer (score 0):

Give background color white to the fragment layout.

replace
   `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

with
  `android:background="color/white"`

Answer (score 0):

You must use`replce()` when you want replace fragment with another fragment in your case you just added fragment to your activity so define all your first `RelativeLayout` inside a new Fragment then use a `FrameLayout` as main container